# Python, Catch value in text file

Tags: python, get

I have a file (output of fluiddynamic code) in which I want to get the value written just after a line that start with `dilute dimensional Zimm longest`

here is reported the interested lines:

```
 dilute dimensional Zimm longest relaxation time, dil_chtime=
    3.29486769328041
```

so far I just wrote this line :
but I don't know why It doesn't catch the value 3.2948676932....

```
 zimm = 0.
  with open('memo.dat','r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines() :
            if(line.startswith(' dilute dimensional Zimm longest')):
                print (line)
                zimm = f.readline() # I suppose that this read the next line
             else:
                pass
```

the output of this frame is :
`dilute dimensional Zimm longest relaxation time, dil_chtime=`
how can I get the value ?

Comment: You should do `zimm = f.next()` instead.

Comment: @RickM. Well first of all that's not going to work because the file has already been read in its entirety by `f.readlines()`, and secondly you really should do `next(f)` instead because that's compatible with python 3.

Comment: @Aran-Fey True, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `next(f)` to fetch the next line

**Ex:**

```
with open('memo.dat') as f:
    for line in f:     #Iterate Each Line
        if line.strip().startswith('dilute dimensional Zimm longest'): #Check Condition
            print(next(f))     #Get Value
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

memo.dat:

```
dilute dimensional Zimm longest relaxation time, dil_chtime=

    3.29486769328041
```

**Python 2.x**:

```
zimm = 0.
nextLine = False     # a boolean flag to get the next line
with open('memo.dat', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()    
    # you may also want to remove empty lines
    content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]
    for line in content:
        try:
            if (line.startswith('dilute dimensional Zimm longest')):
                nextLine = not nextLine
            elif nextLine:
                print(line)
                nextLine = not nextLine
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
3.29486769328041
```

**Python 3.x**:

using `next()`:

```
if (line.startswith('dilute dimensional Zimm longest')):
    print(next(f))
```

Comment: hi shouldnt you put `nextLine=False` before each iteration of loop ?
because that way it will work for multiple lines too.?

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain yes, but inside the `else` block. Thank you!